# Why is Deadshot refered to as the greatest assassin in the DC universe?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In the introduction of Deadshot in the Suicide Squad movie, he is referred to as the greatest assassin.  But references in the comics and video game, "Arkham Origins" consider Slade Wilson, aka, Deathstroke as the greatest assassin in the DC universe, especially considering he has beyond-human capabilities. Considering Deathstroke has a place in many stories related to the heroes of the Justice League, including Batman, is this poor writing simply?  Or does Deathstroke not exist in this universe at all?

Comment: Are you sure he was referenced as greatest assassin and not greatest marksman? I am not sure that's why asked.

Comment: I think someone being the greatest, most accurate shot might assume, rightly or wrongly, that this would translate into being the best assassin, if that was their chose profession.

Comment: The DC extended universe is distinct from the comics, the video games and the TV shows. We don't know if Deathstroke exists in the DCEU.

Comment: I don't know if the actual comics make the claim, but the claim of "greatest assassin" does appear to be a thing on the internet in regards to the comics version. [Comicvine](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/deadshot/4005-5763/) mentions it, themselves. Comicvine is unofficial, but generally very reliable.

Comment: There are Deathstroke rumors for DCEU, few claiming him to be part of Suicide Squad sequel

Comment: @AnkitSharma I believe both claims were made.  If I remember the introduction for his character, the claim of best assassin was made. Then later they talked about his kills, including how he never misses and is the best marksman on the planet.  I guess it could be that Deathstroke doesn't exist yet. Maybe they plan on introducing him in an origins fashion, as though he doesn't exist in this universe yet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the introduction Deadshot was not referred as **Greatest Assassin**.

But referred as: **Assassin for hire**/ **Human Arsenal**

[image]

**Most wanted Hitman**

[image]

**Man who never misses**

[image]

[image]

And we do have Deathstroke in DCEU

First Ben Affleck shares cryptic [footage of Batman villain Deathstroke](http://batman-news.com/2016/08/29/ben-affleck-deathstroke-footage/)

And then it was confirmed that [Joe Manganiello is Deathstroke in Ben Affleck’s Batman Film](http://screenrant.com/deathstroke-joe-manganiello-batman-movie/).